# Conversion to arabic text in python

Tags: python, mysql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have data in mysql table with charset- utf-8. I have one pyspark script which loads mysql data and write a parquet file in s3 bucket. While fetching data from mysql i am getting data in below 
Format:

```
'Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø±Ù‚ÙŠØ©'
```

Then i converted it to utf-8 encoding i got below unicode string:

```
'\xc3\x98\xc2\xa7\xc3\x99\xe2\x80\x9e\xc3\x98\xc2\xb4\xc3\x98\xc2\xb1\xc3\x99\xe2\x80\x9a\xc3\x99\xc5\xa0\xc3\x98\xc2\xa9'
```

After that i am decoded it to mac_arabic encoding then i am getting below text:

```
'أ»آ'أôقÄûأ»آ٤أ»آ١أôقÄöأôإ أ»آ)'
```

Is there a way to generate arabic text from any one these string.

below is the code

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
                                       url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name",
                                       driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                                       dbtable="table",
                                       user="root",
                                       password="root"
                                      ).load()

df.show()
```

For columns in table below config is set:
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL

for database below config is set:
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42627 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you load and write the first string? Show us the code you have used. If your initial string is utf-8 encoded you have to decode it with the same encoding, i.e. utf-8.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi i am using sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options().load() to get the whole table in dataframe.

First text is the value i am getting from mysql table after running above command.

Comment: Add a piece of working code to your question please. Including your database configuration. How did you add the string to the db in the first place? How are you configuring `sqlContext`? How are you printing? Which client, etc. btw, your first string is gibberish, no encoding, decoding will convert it back into arabic.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi i have added the code. Please check.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi Is there any other information you need?

Comment: Change your url to `url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?charascterEncoding=utf8"` and let me know whether it works.

Comment: @MehdiSadeghi Yup this is how i got it resolved. By default jdbc doest not fetch data with utf-encoding i had to pass this with jdbc url and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of JDBC driver on your platform is not using UTF-8 encoding by default. As stated in the comments above try to explicitly pass the encoding to the driver:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_name?characterEncoding=utf8",
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
    dbtable="table",
    user="root",
    password="root").load()
```